# Multiple transclusions of separate html

Tags: html, angularjs

I'd like to transclude multiple pieces into one directive. Here is my idea of how I'd set it up.

```
<div id="content" class="mainDirective">
    <div class="sub">
        <ul>
            <li>Everyone</li>
            <li>Development (3)</li>
            <li>Marketing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subButtons">
        <span class="csStIcon add" data-ng-click="addTeam()"></span>
        <span class="csStIcon edit" data-ng-click="editTeam()"></span>
        <span class="csStIcon delete" data-ng-click="deleteTeam()"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><td>Name</td><td>Last name</td><td>Department</td></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My directive template:

```
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <div data-ng-multi-transclude="sub"></div>
        <div class="bottomOptions">
            <span class="csStIcon collapse"></span>
            <div data-ng-multi-transclude="subButtons"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div data-ng-multi-transclude="main"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the final output:

```
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="sub">
            <ul>
                <li>Everyone</li>
                <li data-ng-click="loadDepartment()">Development (3)</li>
                <li data-ng-click="loadDepartment()">Marketing</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomOptions">
            <span class="csStIcon collapse"></span>
            <div class="subButtons">
                <div class="subButtons">
                    <span class="csStIcon add" data-ng-click="addTeam()"></span>
                    <span class="csStIcon edit" data-ng-click="editTeam()"></span>
                    <span class="csStIcon delete" data-ng-click="deleteTeam()"></span>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="main">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Last name</td><td>Department</td></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Development</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible within angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been added in angular 1.5

http://angularjs.blogspot.ca/2016/02/angular-150-ennoblement-facilitation.html

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing this functionality as well, so I wrote [ng-multi-transclude](https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-multi-transclude) -- funnily enough, I hadn't seen this question at the time, just lucked into the same name.

Usage is almost exactly as your question sketches; the only difference is that you use the `name` attribute to pick the "hole" to fill instead of the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this directive using transclude function:

```
app.directive('mainDirective', function($compile) {
    var template = ['<div>',
                    '    <div class="left">',
                    '        <div data-ng-multi-transclude="sub"></div>',
                    '        <div class="bottomOptions">',
                    '            <span class="csStIcon collapse"></span>',
                    '            <div data-ng-multi-transclude="subButtons"></div>',
                    '        </div>',
                    '    </div>',
                    '    <div class="right">',
                    '        <div data-ng-multi-transclude="main"></div>',
                    '    </div>',
                    '</div>'].join('\n');
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: true,
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attr, model, transclude) {
            var places = element.find('[data-ng-multi-transclude]');
            console.log(element);
            places.each(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                var class_ = self.data('ng-multi-transclude');
                transclude(scope.$new(), function(clone, scope) {
                    var item = clone.closest('.' + class_);
                    $compile(item)(scope).appendTo(self);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I've used compile so you can use angular inside your transcluded code.

If you use this:

```
self.replaceWith($compile(item)(scope));
```

you'll don't get those original wrappers divs with `data-ng-multi-transclude` attributes.

Also you need to have jQuery included (always before Angular, because otherwise you get jQLite instead).

Answer (score 0):

I have used multiple 'transclusions' in the component I am writing. In practice, it's just nested directives but they get the job done: https://github.com/AlexCppns/ac-fancy-input

More specifically, have a look at the following file:

https://github.com/AlexCppns/ac-fancy-input/blob/master/src/ac-fancy-input/directives/fancy-input.js