# Duplicate attributes when using directive compile with transclude

Tags: angularjs

JsFiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/UYf7U/

When using the angularJs transclude within a directives compile, it will duplicate any 
attribute properties. I.e.

```
<a class="myClass">my link</a>
```

Will become

```
<a class="myClass myClass">my link</a>
```

Similarly, when using an ngClick

```
<a ng-click="myFunction()"> my link</a>
```

Will become

```
<a ng-click="myFunction() myFunction()"> my link</a>
```

The fiddle demonstrates this, and unfortunately it crashes. It's a stripped down version of what I'm trying to implement.

Is there a way around this? I've posted the issue to github to: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2576

When clicking on Hello the word "clicked" should appear in an alert.

Comment: why do u want to manually transclude in directive

Comment: As I said, this is a stripped down version of what I'm doing. The reason being I want to have multi-transclude which angualrJs currently does not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different way to do multi-transclusion and that fixed my problem entirely, here's the updated fiddle for my problem being fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/UYf7U/1/

The code came from my previous question here: [Multiple transclusions of separate html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740033/multiple-transclusions-of-seperate-html?lq=1) in an update that I did not see.

The fiddle will be out of date, but this is my final multi transclusion function. I've mode the logic into compile instead of the controller so that it can transclude dom that needs to have things like ng-repeat

```
.directive('multiTranscludeTo', function($rootScope){
    return {
        compile: function(tElement, tAttributes, transclude){
            var baseScope = this;
            transclude($rootScope, function(clone){
                for (var x = 0; x < clone.length; x++){
                    var child = angular.element(clone[x]);
                    var viewName = child.attr('data-multi-transclude-from') || child.attr('multi-transclude-from');
                    if (viewName && viewName.split(" ")[0] == tAttributes["multiTranscludeTo"]){
                        tElement.html(clone[x].innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

This happens because myDirective is being initialized twice - first as part of your markup:

```
 <div class="transcludeMe">
     <div data-transclude-this="here">
         <div class="myDirective"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Second in the `transcludeMe` directive - since you do this in the compile stage of the directive initialization:

```
transcludeHere[0].innerHTML = clone[x].innerHTML
```

Since you use `replace:true` all attributes of the original element will get copied to the template element. If you remove this your example works, but you still be aware that `myDirective` is getting initialized two times: http://jsfiddle.net/tkzgG/

Comment: I would like to use the replace, is there a way around it? Can i be doing the original transclusion differently?

Comment: You could do it in the controller instead, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EwCDW/

Comment: I tried that before, but then I wouldn't be able to do things like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EwCDW/1/

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you want to do - I just try to explain why your code isn't working. myDirective gets compiled before transcludeMe directive. So in transcludeMe you can't see the pre compiled version of myDirective, and if you try to add it manually it will get recompiled. Anyway, here's a different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/4cbu9/

Comment: I'm attempting to do multi-transcluding, thanks for the help though.

Comment: What's multi-transcluding?

Comment: My original quesiton about multi transcluding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740033/multiple-transclusions-of-seperate-html. Which references http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 1):

How important is it to you to specify the directive name as a class? This issue does not occur when the directives are used as elements directly.

See http://jsfiddle.net/smmccrohan/cfP3U/

Like thus, plus replacing the `restrict: 'C'` with `restrict: 'E'` in the directive definitions (and making some case changes to avoid an issue there):

```
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
     <transcludeme>
         <div data-transclude-this="here">
             <mydirective />
         </div>
     </transcludeme>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The alert doesn't fire when you click on "hello".

Comment: Interesting. I've updated the fiddle. With the child directive replicated outside of the parent, the alert now fires on BOTH instances. A scoping issue of some sort, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included a link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smmccrohan/cfP3U/3/

Comment: I should of been more explicit, sorry. But there should be a scope: true on the myDirective part. With that it no longer fires the alert for the one I need.