# How to apply a directive after a transclusion in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to access a *transcluded element* in an *element directive* from a different *inner directive* applied within the first directive's template.

### My (trivial example) setup:

#### Element directive

```
.directive('elementDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      elem.find('transclusion').replaceWith(transclude());
    }
  };
})
```

#### Template

```
<div inner-directive>
  <div id="transclusion"></div>
</div>
```

#### Inner Directive

```
.directive('innerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      //Do something here with child elements (which will be transcluded).
      var some = elem[0].querySelector('[name]');
      //...
    }
  };
})
```

#### Html

```
<element-directive>
  <input name="input_name" />
</element-directive>
```

### My Error:

I get an error of the kind.

```
element-directive element has no child input elements with a 'name' attribute
```

I'm assuming this means that the inner directive is compiled, linked, whatnot, *before* transclusion happens.  So, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: need to tell angular where to transclude within your template  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, i forgot to include that part.  will edit now. i am doing so in my code.

Comment: create a demo then in plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: This is the plunker but I can't get it to do anything... http://plnkr.co/edit/qDQo39f7mm5aT2uwlFrZ

Comment: several issues , you weren't using `ng-transclude` , your `find` wasn't looking for valid element selector. `elem.$attr` was throwing error...should be `elem.attr`  Here's simplified working version  http://plnkr.co/edit/omLiHMlHF03qrqK6Ze1R?p=preview

Comment: also your demo was using `restric` not `restrict`

Comment: @charlietfl It was the ng-transclude.  Thanks.

Comment: And if you want to use transclude function here is a code in my answer to other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740033/multiple-transclusions-of-separate-html/24579241#24579241 you need to append to DOM inside a callback.